# PHPlot drawing only chosen records

Tags: php, html, mysql, phplot

im doing a plot of my measured temperature. I thought it would be nice to use phplot to draw the plot for the temperature for example in last day. But phplot draws every single record from base. Is there any option to set something like phplot could every tenth record?
The code i use is simple:

```
<?php
//Include the code
require_once 'phplot/phplot.php';

//Define the object
$plot = new PHPlot(800,400);

//Set titles
$plot->SetTitle("Wykres temperatury od czasu");
$plot->SetXTitle('Data');
$plot->SetYTitle('Temperatura');

mysql_connect("", "", "");
mysql_select_db("");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT data,temperatura FROM arduino ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 3");

$data = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$plot->SetDataValues($data);

//Turn off X axis ticks and labels because they get in the way:
$plot->SetXTickLabelPos('none');
$plot->SetXTickPos('none');

//Draw it
$plot->DrawGraph();
?>
```

Comment: You need to supply code for context.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].